# Show / Hide multiple div and disable hidden input with multiple checkboxes JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am new to JavaScript and have working code for 1 div hide/show if the correct 2 checkbox checked but cannot get additional checkboxes to work. I have no errors, just does not show other hidden div.

```
$(function() {
  var checkboxstat = $("#triggerSTAT");
  var checkbox = $("#trigger");
  var hidden = $("#hidden_fields");
  var hidden_f = $("hidden_field");
  var checkbox2 = $("#trigger2");
  var nogales = $("#hidden_nogs");
  var nogi = $("#hidden_nogi");

  hidden.hide();
  nogales.hide();

  checkbox.change(function() {

      if ($('#trigger').is(':checked') && $('#triggerSTAT').is(':checked')) {
        hidden.prop('disabled', false).show();
        hidden_f.prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        hidden.prop('disabled', true).hide();
        hidden_f('disabled', true);
        $("#hidden_field").disabled("disabled");
      } else
      if ($('#trigger2').is(':checked') && $('#triggerSTAT').is(':checked')) {
        nogales.prop('disabled', false).show();
        nogi.prop('disabled', false);
      }
    } else {
      nogales.prop('disabled', true).hide();
      nogi('disabled', true);
      $("#hidden_nogi").disabled("disabled");
    }
  });
});
```

I need to have 5 combinations of checkbox checked with `#triggerSTAT` **i.e**. `#trigger3 && #triggerSTAT`.

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 ">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
     </label>
  <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" name="SO" id="triggerSTAT" value="<? echo $SO ?>" /> </div>
<div class="col-xs-5 text-center">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
     <input type="checkbox" id="trigger" name="CNF" value="01"/> 
     1
     </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
     <input  type="checkbox" name="CNF" id="trigger2" value="02"/> 
     2
     </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
     <input  type="checkbox" name="CNF" id="trigger3" alue="03"/>
     3
     </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
     <input type="checkbox"  name="CNF" id="trigger4" value="04"/>
     4
     </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
     <input type="checkbox" name="CNF" id="trigger5" value="05"/>
     5
     </label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5" id="hidden_fields">
  <input class="form-control input-sm text-center" id="hidden_field" name="DOG" type="hidden" value="<? echo $DOG ?>" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5" id="hidden_nogs">
  <input class="form-control input-sm text-center" id="hidden_nogi" name="NOG" type="hidden" value="<? echo $NOG?>" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5" id="hidden_sierv">
  <input class="form-control input-sm text-center" id="hidden_srv" name="SRV" type="hidden" value="<? echo $SRV?>" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5" id="hidden_saff">
  <input class="form-control input-sm text-center" id="hidden_sfrd" name="SAF" type="hidden" value="<? echo $SAF?>" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5" id="hidden_catl">
  <input class="form-control input-sm text-center" id="hidden_cat" name="CAT" type="hidden" value="<? echo $CAT?>" />
</div>
</div>
```

It appears my problem is when I add the `}else if`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function ():

```
$(function() {
 // HIDE FIELDS
$('#hidden_field').hide();
$('#hidden_field').children(":input").prop("disabled", true); // disable
$('#hidden_nogs').hide();
$('#hidden_nogs').children(":input").prop("disabled", true); // disable


$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {

 if($('#1').is(':checked') && $('#triggerSTAT').is(':checked'))  
$('#hidden_field').prop('disabled', false).show(), $('#hidden_field').children(":input").prop("disabled", false);
// KEEP FIELDS HIDDEN
else{
 $('#hidden_field').hide(),$('#hidden_field').children(":input").prop("disabled", true).hide();}
if($('#2').is(':checked') && $('#triggerSTAT').is(':checked'))  
$('#hidden_nogs').prop('disabled', false).show(),          $('#hidden_nogs').children(":input").prop("disabled", false);

 // KEEP FIELDS HIDDEN
else{

 $('#hidden_nogs').hide(),$('#hidden_nogs').children(":input").prop("disabled", true).hide();
    }

});
});
```